# Magento: why can't I update all products from admin grid?

Tags: magento

I go into manage products, select all and then update attributes. Magento churns away and comes back with '999' products successfully updated. That's an odd number! I had selected 3073 products, why only 999 of them updated?

I have noticed this on a couple of projects now, there seems to be a limit on 'collection size' for what can be updated from the admin grid. In my own code I have also noticed a problem with collection size returned, although on this project it wasn't 999 - some other arbitrary number.

None of them have missing SKUs so I don't think the thousandth product is somehow interrupting the collection selection.

Has anyone else experienced this, and, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP Version => 5.3.22

Comment: It also runs the abomination known as cPanel in this instance but I have seen this collection size problem on Ubuntu 10.04 as well as the CentOS/cPanel efforts.

Comment: I am having same issue. did you find solution?

Comment: Same here, would appreciate an answer. Magento community actually closed the topic on me.